# Swift: why is `@escaping` needed?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, escaping, closures

I mean, if the compiler forces one to add the notation, then it seems to me that it already understands it is an escaping block.

Why then force the programmer to add it?

Danks

Comment: One could make the same argument for other keywords. If you mutate state within a struct function, why do you have to annotate it with "mutating"? Annotation helps the compiler *and* the API consumers (including yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@escaping` to differentiate the type of closure because:

1. not all closures are “[escaping](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID546)” (sure, we use that escaping pattern for asynchronous methods, but for functional programming patterns, closures are generally non-escaping); and
2. there are certain optimizations (e.g., how it handles memory calls behind the scenes) that the compiler can do with non-escaping closures that are not possible with escaping ones.

Bottom line, the `@escaping` qualifier is necessary to let the compiler to know which optimizations it can do.

Besides, we should always be able to look at an interface and easily deduce whether the closure is escaping or not. In the absence of some qualifier, it would be much harder to reason about one’s code.

---

FWIW, because non-escaping closures do not introduce the same sort of strong reference cycle risks that escaping ones do, the compiler permits more natural references to properties in non-escaping closures in comparison to escaping closures. By including/excluding the `@escaping` qualifier, the compiler also knows how to handle `self` references inside the closure.

---

In the distant past, closures defaulted to escaping and we had to annotate the non-escaping ones with `@noescape`. Then, as a result of [SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md), the default for closures changed to non-escaping, thereby deprecating the old `@noescape` annotation, but requiring us to annotate escaping closures with `@escaping`.

Comment: Hypothetically, if the escaping attribute didn’t exist, the compiler could still make the non-escaping-closure optimizations, for functions within the same module. But once we start crossing module boundaries, then every closure would have to be pessimistically assumed to be escaping.

Comment: Hypothetically, maybe it could, but (a) it doesn’t; and (b) it would require some pretty heavy lifting. And I’m not sure I’d ever want the compiler to do do that, regardless, as it would be somewhat antithetical to the broader concept that someone (whether the compiler or a human) should be able to look at the interface and easily infer the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It’s part of the public API of your function. Changing from a non-escaping to an escaping closure is a breaking change.

The annotation exists to make that explicit.

Here's an example of it being a breaking change:

```swift
func f(_ closure: /* @escaping */ () -> Void) {
    closure()
}

struct AStruct {
    var i = 0
    
    mutating func mutate() {
        f { i += 1 }
    }
}
```

If `f` takes a non-escaping closure, all is well. But if you make it `@escaping`, you get `error: escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`.

There are several other possible errors related to closure captures being able to effectively make structs into reference types (thereby destroying any guarentees that come from being a value-type)

Comment: I've added an example to better clarify what I meant, too.